# List of strings in prepared statement using Doctrine DBAL

Tags: php, doctrine, dbal

Following the Doctrine DBAL documentation I should be able to bind a list of string values like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield IN (?)';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('myfield', array('stringa', 'stringb', 'stringc'), \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);

$stmt->execute();
```

This results in a PHP notice and kills my script.

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\www\eurocampings\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php on line 142
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 9):

From doctrine documenation:

```
$stmt = $conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id IN (?)',
    array(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)),
    array(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY)
);
```

For those still having problem with binding array of values, Use the PARAM_INT_ARRAY or the PARAM_STR_ARRAY constants with the 'executeQuery' method instead of binding it to the prepared statement.
This is the only way it works.

Comment: He asked decision for `$stmt->bindValue` + `$stmt->execute()` but not for `$conn->executeQuery`. I don't upvote and don't downvote.

Answer (score 8):

From Doctrine DBAL documentation:

> The parameter list support only works with Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::executeQuery() and Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::executeUpdate(), NOT with the binding methods of a prepared statement.

It is on the end of this link:
http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion

Comment: Might have been nice if they also told us that it only works with positional parameters (i.e., "?" placeholders) rather than named parameters. I just spent many minutes working that out.

Answer (score -2):

Try with change the following code:

```
$stmt->bindValue('fcodes', array('stringa', 'stringb', 'stringc'), \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);
```

With the below code:

```
$stmt->bindValue('fcodes', "'stringa', 'stringb', 'stringc'", \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY)
```

Hope it will work as the error show to you on the basis of that.

Comment: Manual quoting values - for generally unknown DBMS, may be not MySQL, not Postgre but somethin other - and inline joining in string is bad practice. 
And of course the `, \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY` is wrong because you alredy do all the job and specify inline string - your type is wrong.

Answer (score -3):

Use Doctrine\DBAL\Types::SIMPLE_ARRAY instead of \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY

For example

```
$values = ['stringa', 'stringb', 'stringc'];
$statement->bindValue ('column_name', $values, Doctrine\DBAL\Types::SIMPLE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: provide more details.

Comment: Not here. In your answer.

Comment: Not worked. When you suggest, please try to do what you said.